# Cleaner view with class="name1", class="name2" and jQuery regexp or not use numbers in class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got two options, this: `<p class="dayFlag@(day.OwnRequest)">`

or this:

```
                        @if (day.OwnRequest == 1)
                    {
                        <p class="dayFlag canWork"></p>
                    }
                    else if (day.OwnRequest == 2)
                    {
                        <p class="dayFlag canNotWork"></p>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <p class="dayFlag"></p>                            
                    }
```

The first option is mutch cleaner. But it is more simple to find the tag witch option 2.

```
var dayFlag = dayHolder.find('.dayFlag');
```

What is best practices in those cases? Got some javascript on the page, working with the tag. Is it 'heavy' to always get it by data attr or use the class with some regexp to see if there are any number after the dayFlaxX

Comment: Use data. jQuery parses it only once, after that it does not even search in the DOM it retrieves it from the javascript so faster than doing things with classes and such...

Comment: Didnt know that, thank you! The reason i asked is because I read some that it can be 'heavy' to work with the data attr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain a little more my comment:

jQuery's data function can be used to retreive and store ANY kind of javascript data to a DOM element. Since jQuery caches the DOM elements, it is not stored in the DOM at all, it simply is linked to it internally.

This method of storing data is one of the easiest to use and one of the fastest when you need to link data to DOM elements.

A little catch is to be avoided though, as it is described above, jQuery does not store directly in the data attribute of the DOM element. So if you have this piece of HTML: `<a href="#" data-linkto="homepage">Link</a>` you could, find this element with the attribute selector like $('[data-linkto]') to add your onclick event listener.

But if, after some user interaction, you do $mylinkelement.data('linkto','nowhere'), this element will not be found with the selector as it does NOT have the attribute data-linkto.